# How to access dataLayer variables

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On our website we have a data layer to define some variables to be passed on to Google Analytics.  It is defined like this:

```
deviceCategory: "DESKTOP"
deviceMode: "DESKTOP"
domainName: ".mydomain.com"
environment: "production"
operatingSystem: "UNKNOWN"
page.category.pageType: "Content"
page.category.primaryCategory: "main"
page.pageInfo.language: "en"
page.pageInfo.pageID: "productSelection"
user.profile.address.city: "Los Angeles"
user.profile.address.country: "US"
```

When I type the following in console it outputs exactly as expected:
dataLayer[0].deviceMode --> "DESKTOP"

However, when I try to access any of the page/user variables I get errors:
dataLayer[0].page.category.pageType --> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Any idea why this is happening? What is the proper way to access these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys you are using are just strings with dots in them. They are not parts of an object, so you would need to access like this:

```
dataLayer[0]['page.pageInfo.language']
```

using the square brackets.

Edit: Note that this is not what you would do in GTM though (but perhaps no need to comment more since you're not asking about that).